# Preventing close with (X) button in window

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How to disable (<kbd>X</kbd>) button in window.

I tried with  some properties like titlebar=no/0 in `window.open` but it is not working fine. Can anybody help me with this query?

Comment: But i am sure for some sites when clicked opens popup and in that close button is disabled

Comment: Those are probably not real popups, but HTML overlays or something.

Comment: Where you saw? that close button is disabled

Comment: Sorry I really dont remember it.

Comment: Same as suggested I handled using unload() with set of conditions. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this page](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Javascript-1520/Prevent-Closing-Page.htm) and [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536973(VS.85).aspx). You can handle the `onunload` event, but there's nothing you can do to prevent a window from being closed; the best you can do prompt the user if they want to "navigate away from the page".

Comment: I did similar workout, but first I called window.close();

In body have a method onunload="muMethod();"

in this method have few boolean conditions as well as if condition  to perform the activity.

Comment: But apart from this is there any other suggestion for performance tuning.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable a close button as wj32 said the best thing you can do is show a warnign if they are closing the window.